# OPENSSL Error: The input data looks too long to be a hash

Tags: openssl, openssl-engine, openssl-net

I am trying to generate and verify the signature with a private key. Its a very straight forward process. However, I am facing this issue.

```
clear
Echo "Generate EC KeyPair from OpenSSL command line"
Echo "1. Create the EC key:"
  openssl ecparam -genkey -name prime192v1 > key.pem 
Echo "`n2.Set it to ANSI Encoding now"
cmd /c pause

Echo "`n3. Extract the public key:"
  openssl ec -in key.pem -pubout > pub.pem
cmd /c pause
Echo "`n4. Calculate the hash:"
  openssl dgst -sha256 -binary random.bin > hash.txt
cmd /c pause
Echo "`n5. Sign the hash with the private key:"
  openssl pkeyutl -sign -inkey key.pem -in hash.txt > sig.txt
cmd /c pause
Echo "`n6. Verify the signature with the public key:"
  openssl pkeyutl -verify -in hash.txt -sigfile sig.txt -inkey key.pem
Echo "`n"type here
```

I expect the signature verification to be successful, as I have made no changes whatsoever.

Here is my dummy data attached. I have tried with multiple size but I face the same error. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpxzA.png)

OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021